# login problem with Subway surfers

Tags: facebook, games, nokia-lumia-630

Since yesterday I am unable to login to facebook account from subway surfers game,while network is o.k & ms facebook app is working as usual. I tried to logout, login from main app but with no luck. I contacted killoo support team but they sent me a link to windows phone support website. They also mailed me on that matter & says it is a device related problem.
Anybody faces same problem? 
From Bing search I came to know that in android such problems occurs but for those problems only android specific solves are available. 
Is there any WP related solve?

Comment: You should try contacting their support.

Comment: Uninstall the Facebook app, restart the phone and login on Subway surfer. It was given as a solution to the same problem on Android. Since this solution is not specific to Android I hope it works on WP.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

- Reinstall Subway Surfers
- Try to log in. If it doesn't work, continue to step 2.

### Step 2

- Uninstall Subway Surfers
- Uninstall Facebook
- Restart the phone
- Install Facebook
- Log in to Facebook
- Install Subway Surfers
- Log in to Subway Surfers using Facebook

*If it still doesn't work, you can try resetting your phone (remember to back up before).*